# Formula Field to set the condition as blank or equal to 0

Tags: formula, formula-field

I need to set the condition of my formula to be blank or  0 , please see the formula as below,

```
If(ISBLANK(TEST__C) OR (TEST__c == 0)  , VALUA ,VALUEB)
```

Note : Basic idea is if TEST__C is balnk or having 0 value then ...value A should go or else value b
kindly help

Comment: Whenever you're running into an error (and this formula should be giving you an error when you try to save it), it is _always_ a good idea to include the error message that you're getting (word-for-word, do not try to paraphrase it). This was a simple enough mistake (and formula) that the issue is pretty easy for experienced eyes to pick up on, but for more complex/less obvious issues, having the error message helps narrow things down. It makes it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax for using OR Function is-

```
OR(condtion1, condition2, ...)
```

Your can update your formula like given below-

```
IF(OR(ISBLANK(TEST__c), TEST__c == 0) , VALUA , VALUEB)
```

OR you can also use pipe symbol-

```
IF( (ISBLANK(TEST__c) || TEST__c == 0) , VALUA , VALUEB)
```

Comment: Also worth noting that you could get rid of the `ISBLANK()` and the need for `||` or `OR()` entirely by setting the formula field to _treat blanks as zeros_.